# How should I create a link to a directory within the same subdomain?

Tags: html, ftp-client

I currently have an index file saved under a url of the form `subdomain.domain.com/directory1`. Within directory 1, I have another directory called `directory2`. To access the index page for `directory2` I have used a link of the form `<a href="/directory2">Link</a>`.

I would have expected this link to lead the user to the page `subdomain.domain.com/directory1/directory2` when clicked, but instead it directs to `subdomain.domain.com/directory2`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the complete path:

```
<a href="/directory1/directory2">Link</a>
```

That happens because you're using a relative url.

Edit~:

For instance: [What is relative URL?](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/relative-URL.html)

Lets assume your script (index.html in this example) is being executed at `http://example.com/` with this folder structure:

```
index.html
uploads/
   - img.jpg
images/
   - banners/
       - banner1.jpg
       - banner2.jpg
```

If you want to create a link to 'uploads' folder, all you have to do is

```
<a href="uploads/">go to uploads</a>
```

That is *because they are in the same structure level*.

In the other hand, if you want to link one of the banners, you'd have to "navigate" trough `images` and then `banners`. It means that *relative* to your script, there is `images/banner/`,

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by relative url? I thought any link of the form /directory looked for that directory within the current one?

Comment: I found an explanation here (http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/relative-URL.html) about what are relative urls.